# How can I make cursor vertical alignment to middle if the input text tag height is more than the text height?

Tags: html, css

When I use the following code, text box size is increased to 300px, but when I type the text in it, it aligns at the top left corner. I want text to be aligned vertically in the center left rather than the top left.

```
<input type="text" style="valign:middle; with:250px;height:300px;">
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: A god idea is to show your code and what you have tried.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen The code was just hidden because it of the `<>` since it wasn't marked as code.

Comment: The caret is already in the vertical middle of the input. http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jsKy8/ . What do you need...really large text?

Comment: Hey all, when i used above code ,text box size increased to 300px but when I type the text in it it aligns at top left corner what i want text to be aligned vertically middle

Comment: in your fiddle, if I delete "valign:middle; ", the carat is still aligned in the middle vertically.

Answer (score 1):

you want this?

```
<input type="text" 
style="text-align:center;valign:middle; width:250px;height:300px;">
```

otherwise it's unclear for me..

Comment: Hey Christian, when i used above code ,text box size increased to 300px but when I type the text in it it aligns at top left corner what i want text to be aligned vertically middle. thanks

Comment: @reachyathish: then something is odd about your code. maybe you have already defined "input" in a css-file or any global style definition? this code, simply wrapped in a html and a body tag, will create a box where the cursor is both, horizontal and vertical centered.. i have tested it.. please look for any style definitions on input or try another browser. alternatively, show us more/the full code..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding line-height

```
<input type="text" style="valign:middle; with:250px;height:300px;line-height:300px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research found this:

```css
input { line-height: normal; }
```